# Find date in range gives blank

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=IFERROR((INDEX(TRACKER!$A$2:$A$500, SMALL(IF(AND($B$3<=TRACKER!$C$2:$C$500,$B$4>=TRACKER!$C$2:$C$500),ROW(TRACKER!$C$2:$C$500)-MIN(ROW(TRACKER!$C$2:$C$500))+1, ""), ROW($A1)))),"")
```

That pulls data depending on the beginning IF(AND( statement. I was trying to get it to pull dates that are between B3 and B4 (so, >=B3 but <=B4)

The problem is, it doesn't seem to like my AND statement and keeps pulling nothing (""). If I delete one of the statements in the AND and just pull >=B3 or <=B4, it works fine...so it's not a date formatting issue.

Would appreciate any way to incorporate date range into this array formula, thank you.

Comment: Array formulas do not like `AND` or `OR` multiply the two boolean statements together instead.

Comment: Perfect Scott, thank you very much as always for the swift and concise response. I replaced it with a "*" and it all worked out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Scott, thank you very much as always for the swift and concise response. I replaced it with a "*" and it all worked out. Appreciate it.

Comment: Please refrain form leaving comments here as solutions. Before posting a solution, ask yourself if someone else who has the same problem would read this solution and know how to fix the issue.Probably not. `I replaced it with a "*"` .... What is `it`? Replace what with `*`?